# iPhone - UISearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I’m trying to select a search bar in code. I want to make like a touch event on the search bar in the Viewdidload so that the keyboard will be shown when i navigate to the view. Any one knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In a tableview, typically you want to use the [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) In viewDidLoad you could set it to active using this property:

```
@property(nonatomic, getter=isActive) BOOL active
```

eg: `_search.active = YES;`